# При сборке проекта на objective-c в xcode9 под iOS11 смещаются созданные из кода subViews относительно navigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

Проблема в следующем: проект написан на objective-c, все UI-элементы созданы из кода. На первом контроллере помимо navigation Bar добавляется скролл View во весь экран(включая navigation Bar) и в него добавляются несколько subView. При сборке проекта в Xcode 8 все элементы отображались верно, без смещений см.рисунок. Но при сборке проекта в Xcode 9 под iOS11, все subView добавляемые мною в ScrollView размещаются не с самого верха экрана, а с отступом, равным высоте navigation Bar. Если его сделать Hidden то окна перемещаются вверх как положено, видимо в iOS11 по умолчанию элемент типа NavigationBar находится в safe Area, как управлять границами safe Area из кода Objective-c найти нигде не могу. Прилагаю код создания скролла и окон... Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, пожалуйста подскажите как пофиксить safe Area из кода.

```
mainNavigationController = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMenuViewController];
mainNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
mainNavigationController.delegate = self;
mainNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIWindow* window = self.window;
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
window.rootViewController = mainNavigationController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

UIView* mainView = [[[MainViewControllerView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame] autorelease];
self.view = mainView;

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scrollView.bounces = NO;

[scrollView addSubview:myLogoView];
[scrollView addSubview:littleScrollView];
[scrollView addSubview:firstButton];
[scrollView addSubview:secondButton];
[scrollView addSubview:thirdButton];
[scrollView addSubview:fouthButton];
[scrollView addSubview:fifthButton];
[scrollView addSubview:sixthButton];
[scrollView addSubview:seventhButton];
[scrollView addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
```

![Скриншоты]https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttrkolgnch80kr9/safeArea.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема из-за `scrollView.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`. В iOS 11 этот метод deprecated, попробуйте задать `scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever`.

Comment: Вы совершенно ПРАВЫ! Большое вам, человеческое СПАСИБО!!!